# How to solve the recurrence $a_{n}=\frac{n+1}{n} a_{n-1}+3n+3$?

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms

I tried to solve this recurrence by taking out $n+1$ as a common in the RHS, but still have $n \cdot a_n$ and $a_n$

Comment: Is it $n+ \frac1n$, or $\frac{n+1}n$?

Comment: the second one , seems I did make mistake I will edit it know

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**

$$a_{n}=\frac{n+1}na_{n-1}+3n+3,$$
$$
na_n= (n+1)a_{n-1} + 3n(n+1)
$$

$$
\frac{a_n}{n+1}=\frac{a_{n-1}}n +3
$$

Comment: thanks, I already approach this step but at the second step how to get rid of n a(n) and a(n) ??

Comment: If you are asking about how to go from the 2nd line to the 3rd line, divide both sides by $n(n+1)$.

Comment: yes, after that if I'm assuming that $b_{n}=a_{an}/n+1$,, how could I deal with $a_{n-1}/n$ ?? it's not over n+1 so I can say that $b_{n-1}=a_{n-1}/n+1$

Comment: $a_{n-1}/n = b_{n-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Assuming you meant $\frac{n+1}{n}$ (since you stated that you factored $n+1$ from the rhs), you can divide by $n+1$ and define 
$$b_n=\frac{a_n}{n+1}.$$

Now, what is the equation satisfied by $b_n$? Do you know how to solve such an equation?

Answer (score 0):

$$a_{n}=\Big(\frac{1}{n}+n\Big)a_{n-1}+3(n+1)$$
Divide by
$$\prod_{k=1}^{n}\Big(\frac{1}{k}+k\Big)$$
To give
$$\frac{a_{n}}{\prod_{k=1}^{n}\big(\frac{1}{k}+k\big)}=\frac{a_{n-1}}{\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\big(\frac{1}{k}+k\big)}+\frac{3(n+1)}{\prod_{k=1}^{n}\big(\frac{1}{k}+k\big)}$$
Let
$$A_{n}=\frac{a_{n}}{\prod_{k=1}^{n}\big(\frac{1}{k}+k\big)}$$
To give 
$$A_{n}-A_{n-1}=f(n)$$
Where $f(n)=\frac{3(n+1)}{\prod_{k=1}^{n}\big(\frac{1}{k}+k\big)}$. Now sum both sides from $2$ to $n$
$$\sum_{k=2}^{n}(A_{k}-A_{k-1})=\sum_{k=2}^{n}f(k)$$
This is
$$A_{n}-A_{1}=\sum_{k=2}^{n}f(k)$$
Thus
$$A_{n}=A_{1}+\sum_{m=2}^{n}\frac{3(m+1)}{\prod_{k=1}^{m}\big(\frac{1}{k}+k\big)}$$
and
$$a_{n}=\Big(\prod_{l=1}^{n}\big(\frac{1}{l}+l\big)\Big)\Big(\frac{a_{1}}{2}+\sum_{m=2}^{n}\frac{3(m+1)}{\prod_{k=1}^{m}\big(\frac{1}{k}+k\big)}\Big)$$

Comment: thanks ! I will try understand it, since we didn't learn this approach and have to solve it by inhomogeneous technique.